# Design pattern for prioritization of graph nodes

Tags: java, design-patterns, jgrapht

Problem to solve: give a priority (int value) to all the nodes of a graph. There is a DAG class with an attribute Graph (of type DirectedGraph from JGraphT library). Moreover, there must be different algorithms to assign priorities, and it must be possible to add new algorithms in the future without modifying the existing code.
The DAG is created first, and then the user will have the possibility to select which algorithm to use (using a ComboBox in a GUI). The user must have the possibility to change the algorithm at any moment.

Approach 1:
Develop an interface (Algorithm) for the algorithms, and make all the algorithms implement that interface.
In the DAG class, add a new attribute:

```
Algorithm myAlgo;
```

Each time the user selects a different algorithm on the GUI, instantiate that algorithm:

```
myAlgo = new AlgorithmNumberX;
```

Approach 2:
Write the prioritization task independently (not as an attribute of the DAG), use a static method to prioritize the nodes of the DAG, by sending the DAG as an argument and returning the modified DAG.

Which advantages has each approach?

Comment: The Algorithm is not an inherent part of the graph, so I'd not recommend to store it as a field. But I'm not sure why you suggested a `static` method for the second approach. Why not an `interface Algorithm { void workOn(Graph g); }`? (BTW: Are the priorities stored directly in the DAG (or its nodes), or via an external data structure (like a `Map<Node,Integer>` or so)?)

Comment: The priorities are directly stored in the nodes of the DAG. Of course I need to create an interface, so multiple algorithms can be added later on. But the point is I am not sure if the algorithm should be an attribute of the own graph, or an independent issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally go for option 1 (as I recently have). You are basically describing a Strategy pattern (a combination of both options actually). The only problematic thing you may have with that approach is getting the class names to enter into the combo box. You will also need to add an object that creates the instance for you. if you do new Algorithmx you will need to add another such statement for each algorithm you add which is against the requirements you stated.

```
public class AlgorithmStrategy
{
    public static final Algorithm getAlgorithm(String className)
    {
        Algorithm algorithm = null;         
        String name = "<package algorithms are in>." + className;           
        try 
        {
            algorithm = (Algorithm)Class.forName(name).newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        return algorithm;
    }
}
```

In this example Algorithm is your interface. Create each concrete class to implement your interface and work out your priorities accordingly.

Use like:

```
Algorithm algorithm = AlgorithmStrategy.getAlgorithm("Algorithmx");
```

Where "Algorithmx" is retrieved from your combo

Comment: That seems to be a good option to automate the creation of the algorithm according to the selected option in the combo. And yes, the Stratey Pattern is what I need to isolate the changing part of the code, that is the algorithm.

Comment: I think a dot (.) is missing between the package name and the class name onesixtyfourth: String name = "<package algorithms are in>." + className;

Comment: To my understanding, the important point of option 1 was *not* how the algorithm implementation should be obtained, but only whether or not to store the `Algorithm` instance in the graph. A graph consists of vertices and edges - but it does not "contain" or "consist of" an algorithm. There might be situations where such a construct might seem "handy". But at the moment, I don't see a profound reason to include the Algorithm in the Graph here.

Comment: Agreed and in my implementation of this I did not store the reference in the Graph class but passed the Graph into a method defined in the Interface.

Answer (score 1):

Why did you put the Design Patterns tag on this and then not mention them at all?

This is clearly a job for the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

The other thing worth thinking about here is genericizing the graph itself, so having a way to do Graph. That way you could have graphs of anything and be able to score them at will.

The other question here is what is the purpose of this scoring? Ordering, right? So you are basically producing an index, no? And you might want to have other orderings? So some organization where you could contain different orders in groups together would make sense, then you could presumably switch between them without an intervening rebuild (as you mention).

Comment: Sorry not to mention the name of the pattern, I am still a newbie in this field. The purpose is to obtain an ordered list, yes, according to the priority value of each node. But I don´t need different orders at the same time. The prioritization might be done on the fly when the user selects a prio criteria through the GUI.